# kafka + how to change the topic retention hours with kafka cli as kafka-configs

Tags: apache-kafka

we want to change the kafka retention hours to 1 hour

```
kafka-configs.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181  --entity-type topics  --entity-name topic_test --add-config retention.hours=1
Error while executing config command Unknown topic config name: retention.hours
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Unknown topic config name: retention.hours
```

then we try

```
kafka-configs.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181  --entity-type topics  --entity-name topic_test --add-config retention.ms=3600000
Completed Updating config for entity: topic 'test_topic'.
```

**my equation is**

dose `retention.ms` is the same as `retention.hours` but in mili seconds ?

the target is to purge the data Kafka files after 1 hour

but the `kafka-configs.sh` not accept the `retention.hours=1` , so we change it to `retention.ms=3600000`

*as I understand
Retention time is controlled by the cluster-wide as:*

```
log.retention.ms
log.retention.minutes
log.retention.hours
```

*so this configuration properties is from higher to lower
but as I explained kafka cli cant use retention.hours , so this is the reason that I am using `retention.ms=3600000`*

Reference -

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-log-cleanup-policies.html#log-retention
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/installing-configuring-kafka/content/log_settings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retention.hours` does not exist as [a topic config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs)

Comment: so retention.ms can replace it but with milli seconds?

Comment: That's what the documentation says, yes